# Chrome Extension - Optimizing my page load time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension with angularJS. The idea of the extension is to replace the default google page when a user opens a new tab with a simple app.

Therefore, it needs to be fast. I am trying to optimize my page load time. I have minified my javascript and I load all the pictures in async mode.
When I use the chrome dev tools to see what's delaying my page, I find a gap in the waterfall chart. I believe it is due to my js code which is being executed by chrome.

How can I make sure the DOM get printed on the screen while the js is being executed? 
Is there any good tool/resources to see how I can optimize my js with regards to my page load time?

[image]

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/08/improving-smashing-magazine-performance-case-study/

Comment: What about the obvious solution to "make sure the DOM get printed on the screen while the js is being executed": put the script tags after the DOM you want loaded first?